# Matching spacing with conditional versions

Tags: vertical-alignment, conditionals, vfill

I am using an "if" to make two versions of a document (a problem set and an answer key). I would like both versions to have the same vertical spacing while using vfills, but I think that might not be feasible to do in an efficient way.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to make these have the same spacing without trial-and-error estimating?
2. How do you decide when a task isn't worth trying? Is it even worth it to try to fix this issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, bottom=6in]{geometry} % This is to make the MWE more viewable, not a part of the original document
\newif\ifkey
\keytrue % comment out to view student version

\begin{document}

\ifkey Teacher version \else Student version \fi
\begin{enumerate}

\item Question 1


\ifkey key \\ has \\ long \\ answer \fi

\vfill

\item Question 2

\ifkey key has short answer \fi

\vfill


\item Question 3 \ifkey key doesn't take any vertical space \fi

\vfill

\end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

These screenshots aren't great because I couldn't get them side-by-side, but hopefully you get the idea

[image: teacher version (uneven spacing)]

[[image: student version (even spacing)2]

Comment: is this for paper or do you need text not in pdf (on paper \color{white} and \color{black}  hide text with same space but not if you need to hide digital text

Comment: This is on paper. I use it in lots of printed worksheets, guided notes, and tests